# Pagination function in custom href link for camera slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera, jquery-slider

I'm using [Camera Slider](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/). The slider has 3 images that will be automatically sliding.

And I added 3 links out of the slider that positioned with css. Here is my html structure

```
<div class="custom-navigation">
  <a href="#">Slide1</a>
  <a href="#">Slide2</a>
  <a href="#">Slide3</a>
</div>
```

**What I need Exactly**

I need to change slider images when user click on the each links, like slider pagination. simply means when a user click on the **Slide1** `<a href="#">Slide1</a>` the slider shows first slider image and respectively. So how can I give the pagination function to custom `href link`.

Code Demo Here - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPWGKm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.custom-navigation a').click(function(){
    $('.camera_pag_ul li').eq( $(this).index() ).click();
});
```

Just pass the 'click to correspond pagination link' when you click on custom link